# What will passing an array with a single integer to Uint8Array do to the content passed to it?

Tags: javascript, arduino, serial-port

I am experimenting with the Web Serial API (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/web-serial/#3) to read and write data to an Arduino processor (atmega 328p). I couldn't figure out why the message being sent to the board  goes through an Uint8Array in an example I found:

```
const sendToBoard(command) {
      let message = new Uint8Array([command])
      const writer = outputStream.getWriter();
      writer.write(message);
      writer.releaseLock();
}
```

What will passing an array do to the integer passed to Uint8Array and what is its relevance when sending it through a serial port to a board? Could it be done without it?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the example with the led matrix its explained why they use an array they store the values of the individual led in the matrix that way

```
arr.push(cb.checked === true ? 1 : 0);
```

and this is probably the reason why. So you can of course send single values over serial but its more efficient to do bursts of data instead of single values in that scenario (MatrixLED) 
**EDIT**
The **Uint8Array()** constructor creates a typed array of 8-bit unsigned integers. The contents are initialized to 0. Once established, you can reference elements in the array using the object's methods, or using standard array index syntax.
[Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array/Uint8Array) and [in-depth reading](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typedarray-constructors)
Why the dev choose to use exactly this method - you have to write an email to the author of the program.

Comment: your answer definitely added to my knowledge! I still don't understand what Uint8array does

Comment: See my edit (I guess "The contents are initialized to 0"might be the reason)